# Spring Autowire

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have two classes - `ParentCls` and `SubCls`:

```
class ParentCls {
    public ParentCls(int x, int y); 
    ....
}

class SubCls {
    public SubCls(int x, int y, int z) {
        super(x, y);
        // some init codes ..
        this.z = z;
    } 
    ....
}
```

Now I create an instance of `SubCls` by passing x, y, z params and two of them get passed to super class. Instead of doing this way, I am trying to autowire a `Config` object (which has values for x, y, z) into `SubCls`:

```
class SubCls {
    @Autowired
    IConfig config;

    public SubCls() {
        super(x, y);  // <- the problem: config.getX() doesn't work in super()
        // some init codes ..
        this.z = config.getZ();
    } 
    ....
}
```

However, the problem is: I can't use the injected `config` object in `super()`. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: During object construction (at the constructor) Spring can't inject your dependencies because the object itself is not constructed! However, if you need to do something after object's construction and dependency injection phase, you should declare a public method (named "init" or "setup", for instance) and annotate it with @javax.annotation.PostConstruct. Inside this method, you'll have your dependencies fulfilled.

Answer (score 2):

When you do autowiring like that, Spring first creates an instance of `SubCls` using a no-arg constructor, and only then it sets a value for `config`. So inside the constructor you will see a default value for `config`, which is `null`, and calling `config.getX()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, use autowiring for constructor arguments:

```
class SubCls {
    IConfig config; // if you'll need config in the future

    @Autowired
    public SubCls(IConfig config) {
        super(config.getX(), config.getY());
        this.z = config.getZ();
        this.config = config; // if you'll need config in the future
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you "cannot use the injected config object in super", I guess you mean that you get a `NullPointerException`, and that's normal: That's because at the time the superconstructor is invoked, Spring has not already initialized the `config` reference.

I suggest you transform the class `Config` in a singleton, and leave the code like this:

```
class SubCls {
    public SubCls() {
        super(Config.getInstance().getX(), Config.getInstance().getY());
        // some init codes ..
        this.z = config.getZ();
    } 
    ...
}
```